# Smart GWT - button problem with chrome

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

i've a problem with smart-GWT and google Chrome. I don't see the IButton and the ButtonItem as well as Internet Explorer or Forefox 4.

This problem happen when i use an HTML code created with Dreamweaver, that use Table.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using the Table element. CSS with divs are easier to use in the long run.

Having said that, I have found some funny behaviour using the SmartGWT IButton and IE 9.0, I have to render the page in compatibility mode or else the button doesn't work. It works fine in Chrome, but SmartGWT 2.4 was released in Dec 2010, so maybe an update is due out soon that will address this.